# Get FontSize from the InspectorControls Standard Control (typography.fontSize)

Tags: block-editor

I have developed a block and am now trying to determine the size of the font based on the selected FontSize in order to be able to further use this value for calculations.

The font size is selected via the standard control in the Inspector (block-support). Depending on how the size is selected, I get either a class (has-xx-large-font-size) or a style value. I can use the style value directly for further calculations, but unfortunately not the class.

Hence my question. Is there a simple way to determine the font size, or do I have to check whether I have a class myself and then laboriously pick it apart and resolve it against the theme settings?

The block editor offers "getFontSize", but that expects an array with all defined font sizes. Where can I get this? Do I have to read this myself using a REST call, or is there an easier way?

I'm open to any kind of advice, as unfortunately I haven't found any really helpful documentaries on this subject